# PHP проблема с выводом

Tags: сокеты, php, export

У меня есть крон, который в течении нескольких часов выполняет несколько раз в секунду определенные действия, весь результат записывается в т.ч. в лог. В определенное время в лог перестает что-либо писаться, на экран вар_дампами тоже ничего не выводится, хотя крон продолжает работать и выполнять все остальные действия. Происходит это после попытки сделать var_export для данных полученных через сокет. Соответственно данных о том, что там произошло, тоже нет. В чем хотя бы приблизительно может быть проблема (сокет не отвечает, ответил что-то не то и т.д.)? Или, может, кто-то с чем-то подобным (прекращением вывода) сталкивался.

Comment: Уточните, перестает выводится после чтения из сокета или после чтения и попытки это записать в лог?

Comment: После чтения из сокета и попытки записать это в лог!
Если я не ошибаюсь, вместо обычно 200 ОК мне вернулся гет-запрос...

Comment: Приведите кусок кода отвечающего за вывод в лог/stdin и соответствующую строку в crontab.

Answer (score 1):

PHP в принципе не предназначен для создания долго-работающих скриптов (есть заморочки со сборщиком мусора) возможно в вашем скрипте это и проявляется, попробуйте переписать скрипт, что-бы он итерации делал в более "изолированном" окружении, например можно использовать `fork`:

```
$log = fopen("logfile.log", "a");
$list = array(
   "http://ya.ru?text=search"
);
foreach ($list as $url) {
    $pid = pcntl_fork();

    if ($pid == -1) {
        die('could not fork');
    }
    else if ($pid) { // parent
        pcntl_wait($status);
    }
    else { // child
        fwrite($log, file_get_contents($url));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ограничения могут быть на выполнения скрипта. Если есть возможность максимальное время выполнения скрипта в php.ini поменяй или set_time_limit(0); в своём скрипте (но только если на сервере разрешено). Что касается сокетов, socket_blocking и socket_timeout